# simple css animation not working on dynamic reactjs element

Tags: reactjs, css-transitions, css-animations

Check the snippet at codepen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EZJjNO
Click on Add button, it will add another item but its appearing immediately without any fade effect.

JS:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.addItem = this.addItem.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      items: [1,2,3]
    }
  }

  addItem() {
    var items = this.state.items;
    items.push(4);
    this.setState({
      items: items
    })
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        {
          this.state.items.map(function(i) {
            return <div className="item fade">Testing</div>
          })
        }
        <button onClick={this.addItem}>Add</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

React.render(<App />, document.body);
```

CSS:

```
.App {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.5);
  text-align: center;
  height: 100vh;
}
div.item {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #123456;
  color: #fff;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
}
.fade {
  opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the `fade` class is added by default, you don't get the transition effect. If you open your browser's developer tools and remove the class, you'll see it fade away nicely.

There's a few ways to get what you want, but I'd just use a keyframe CSS animation like so:

```
.fade {
  animation: 0.4s ease-out fadeIn 1;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
  }
}
```

[Here's a fork of your code pen](http://codepen.io/selbekk/pen/BpENXJ) showing how it works :)